# when you wish someone makes the job

Tags: sentence-construction

I could have included the question in the title actually. I was wondering how I should use ''looking forward to'' when I want someone else to do something. Namely, which one is correct?

- I am looking forward you to solving the problem?
- I am looking forward to you solving the problem?

Google and Cambridge translators give no difference between them (I have translated them to Spanish), and on-line Cambridge dictionary says nothing about this. And neither does a quick search on Google.

Comment: You don't 'look forward' a person, you 'look forward _to_' something happening - so your second is correct.

Comment: The second one is correct. Definitely.

Comment: By the way, I would like to know if the first one is even grammatical?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Notice that for beginners like me, the first one makes sense as long as it copies the structure of ''I want you to''.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I would say that it was not grammatical because _look forward_ does not take a direct object. Dog_69 - _I want you to solve the problem_ is not the same structure as _I look forward to you solving the problem_.

Comment: @KateBunting True. I was translating it wrong, it does not take direct object, so they are different structures, though they seem quite similar for non-native speakers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely needs the preposition because you are "looking forward" and then stating a *direction* - the thing you are looking forward **to**.

The more formal way of saying "I'm looking forward to" is:

> **I look forward to** you solving the problem.

Your example doesn't sound like something one would say informally, and the above sounds better.

---

If you were to use a verb that doesn't require a direction, then a preposition isn't required, for example:

> I eagerly *anticipate* you solving the problem.

Comment: You're right, the doubt came up when writing a formal Email. So thanks for the suggestion.